# Do constant functions have absolute or local max/mins?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, optimization

Let $f(x) = 4$ for every $x$ real.

> Is $4$ a local max and min and also an absolute max and min?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every point of a constant function is a global maximizer as well as a global minimizer. It is also true that every point is a local maximizer and a local minimizer.

Comment: Thank you I'm in 10th grade couldn't find any useful information.

Comment: @Afonso You are welcome. Something special about $4$ for the function $f(x)=4$ is that it is a [fixed point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_(mathematics)) of $f$.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the derivative to find maximum and minimum. So
$f^\prime (x)=0 \quad \forall x  $. What does it mean?

Comment: This just makes the problem much more complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, yes, it is a minimum and a maximum (even global), as long as you are not concerned with *strict* extrema.