# Local Maximum of $f$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

Let $f: (a,b) \to R$ be a differentiable map and let $x_0 \in (a,b)$ be a critical point. Prove that if there exists $\delta>0$ such that $f’(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in (x_0 - \delta, x_0)$ and $f’(x) \leq 0$ for all $x \in (x_0, x_0 + \delta)$ then $x_0$ is a local maximum of $f$.

I’m having a hard time in getting started here. I tried to use the fact that $f$ is differentiable (the definition) but it got me nowhere. I just need and idea of how can I start this proof! Any help’d be great. Thanks!

Comment: I think the conjecture fails in the case of constant functions. Did you mean $f'(x)<0$ and $f'(x)>0$?

Comment: nvm, constants are all [considered maxima](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1180096)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x_0$ is not a local maximum. Then we should be able to find $x$ such that $|x-x_0| < \delta$ and $f(x) > f(x_0)$. Now apply the mean value theorem to relate the difference $f(x)-f(x_0)$ to the derivative of $f$ evaluated at some point near $x_0$, and use what you know about the sign of the derivative near $x_0$.